# Add variable to Object.query field

Tags: apex, soql

I understand that when doing SOQL queries with apex, you can add variables like so:

```
[Select Id From Account Where Date = :date]
```

But, for instance, I'm creating a pushtopic with a query like so:

```
Date td = Date.today();

pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT (fields) FROM (object) WHERE Date = td';
```

And neither that is working nor adding a colon before 'td'. I'm wondering how to add variables to an object query field.

Comment: This [Supported PushTopic Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/supported_soql.htm) shows that you can include date literals in the query so format your date as a (correctly formatted) string and append that literal to the rest of your query string.

Comment: @KeithC that's fine and all but I want the date to update every day, i.e. I always want the push topic to be pushing only the records that were created 'today'. So, while today appending '2014-10-20' is fine, tomorrow I would want '2014-10-21'

Comment: Try doing something like `String td = String.valueOf(Date.today());`. You can specify the format the string is output in. See the apex docs for more.

Comment: You could run a Schedulable every night to deactivate and re-create with the new date but hardly elegant. Hopefully someone will have a better answer.